# Solve for x using python

Tags: python-3.x, string, optimization, discrete-mathematics, prefix-operator

I came across a problem. One string is taken as input say

```
input_string = "12345 + x = x * 5 + (1+x)* x + (1+18/100)"
```

And get output of x using python. I am not able to figure out logic for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete SymPy example for your input:

```py
from sympy import Symbol, solve, Eq
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

input_string = "12345 + x = x * 5 + (1+x)* x + (1+18/100)"
x = Symbol('x', real=True)
lhs = parse_expr(input_string.split('=')[0], local_dict={'x':x})
rhs = parse_expr(input_string.split('=')[1], local_dict={'x':x})

print(lhs, "=", rhs)
sol = solve(Eq(lhs, rhs), x)
print(sol)
print([s.evalf() for s in sol])
```

This outputs:

```py
x + 12345 = x*(x + 1) + 5*x + 59/50
[-5/2 + 9*sqrt(15247)/10, -9*sqrt(15247)/10 - 5/2]
[108.630868798908, -113.630868798908]
```

Note that `solve()` gives a list of solutions. And that SymPy normally does not evaluate fractions and square roots, as it prefers solutions without loss of precision. `evalf()` evaluates a float value for these expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that example shows a quadratic equation which may have no solutions, one solution, or two solutions. You would have to rearrange the terms symbolically to come to

> input_string = "x**2 + 5*x - 12345 + (118/100)"

But that means you need to implement rules for multiplication, addition, subtraction and potentially division. At least for Python there is a library called [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) which can parse such strings and provide an expression that you can evaluate and even [solve](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/solvers.html).